# First character of string in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, encoding

In Python I have got this string

```
string = "Ľubomír Mezovský"
```

I need to get only first character of it. But when I tried `string[0]` it returned `�`. When I tried `string[:2]` it worked well. My question is why?
I need to run this for several strings and when string does not start with diacritic character, it returns substring of two characters.

I am also using `# encoding=utf8` and Python 2.7

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: I bet you are using Python 2.7. Are you using Python 2.7?

Comment: Interesting; with `utf-8`, it actually takes two characters to represent your first letter.

Comment: No, it is 3.6.4

Comment: In Python 3.x, it should work fine: https://ideone.com/hpE51e , in python 2.x, it outputs as you described: https://ideone.com/yvsPjd

Comment: @falsetru: yep. My bet is still OP's using Python 2.7. Even though OP denies it.

Comment: You are right. I have installed Python 3.6.4, but in some reason PyCharm is using 2.7. I need to take a look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with byte-string (assuming you're using Python 2.x).

Convert the byte-string to unicode-string using [`str.decode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.decode), get the first character, then convert it back to binary string using [`str.encode`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) (optional unless you should use byte-string)

```
>>> string = "Ľubomír Mezovský"
>>> print(string.decode('utf-8')[0].encode('utf-8'))
Ľ
```

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the string to Unicode and the encode to "utf-8"

**Ex:**

```
string = u"Ľubomír Mezovský"
print string[0].encode('utf-8')
```

**Output:**

```
Ľ
```

Tested in **python2.7**